# PHP ZipArchive, disable outputs/echos/logs

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am running PHP ZipArchive in an API and it outputs like `adding: uploads/AUFIC/ps.csv (stored 0%)` in the body of the response when it runs, how can I disable this output from getting printed?

Here's the function that contains ZipArchive, it arranges some files around then zips those files and upload it to S3 then return the URL of that zip file:

```
    private function downloadPackage($schoolPrefix,$schoolZipPassword,$csvFilePath) {
    $ret = array('status' => false, "message" => "", "response" => array());
    try {
        $s3 = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array('region' => getenv('omitted_AWS_REGION_2')));
        $s3->registerStreamWrapper();
        $bucket = 'autoregistration.omitted.com';
        // production needs to be read from env var
        $prefix = 'production/PackageFiles/';
        $objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Prefix' => $prefix
        ));
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $zipfilename = $schoolPrefix.'_omitted'.date('YmdHis').'.zip';
        $zipfilepath = 'uploads/'.$zipfilename;
        $zip->open($zipfilepath, ZipArchive::CREATE);
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            if(basename($object['Key']) != 'PackageFiles')
            {
                $contents = file_get_contents("s3://{$bucket}/{$object['Key']}");
                $objectname = (basename($object['Key']) == 'SchoolPrefix.ps1') ? $schoolPrefix.'.ps1' : basename($object['Key']);
                $zip->addFromString($objectname, $contents);
            }
        }
        // pass the school prefix in params
        $school_objects = $s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Prefix' => 'production/'.$schoolPrefix
        ));
        foreach ($school_objects as $school_object) {
            if(basename($school_object['Key']) == 'ps.csv')
            {
                $contents = file_get_contents("s3://{$bucket}/{$school_object['Key']}");
                $zip->addFromString(basename($school_object['Key']), $contents);
                $foundcsv = true;
            }
        }
        if(!$foundcsv) throw new Exception ('Can not find the csv file.', 400);

        $zip->close();
        $output = system("zip -P '".$schoolZipPassword."' ". $zipfilepath . " ".$csvFilePath);
        $key = 'production/'.$schoolPrefix.'/'.$zipfilename;
        $s3result = $s3->putObject(array('Bucket'=>$bucket,'Key' => $key, 'SourceFile' => $zipfilepath));
        //$ret['s3_url'] = $s3result['ObjectURL'];
        $ret['s3_url'] = $s3->getObjectUrl($bucket, $key, '+2 days');
        $ret['status'] = true;
        unlink($zipfilepath);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $ret['status'] = false;
        $ret['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: sharing the offending code would possibly help others track down the cause of the problem

Comment: @RamRaider I added the function that contains the issue, let me know if that's not enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by changing this:

```
return $ret;
```

To this:

```
return;
```